# Convert String [] into ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to get location name from mysql database. I want to retrieve all location name and collect in `ArrayList` and this List requested by `setAttribute` to jsp.

```
ArrayList<Bean> SupplyLocation = new ArrayList<Bean>();
try {
//...
    while(rs.next()) {
        Bean Location = new Bean();
        String supply[] = (rs.getString("location_name")).split(",");

        for(int i=0; i<supply.length; i++) {
            Location.setLocation(supply);
            SupplyLocation.add(Location);
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you created only one object `Location`, so it will be modified later in for loop, so you will end up with one object with `supply` from `supply[lastIndex]` in that object, and all references in `ArrayList` will point to it.

Fixed:

```
while(rs.next()) {
        String supply[] = (rs.getString("location_name")).split(",");

        for(int i=0; i<supply.length; i++) {
            Bean Location = new Bean();
            Location.setLocation(supply[i]);
            SupplyLocation.add(Location);
        }  
}
```

In this way, you create new object `Bean` for each string in `supply` array, then you set string `supply[i]` to it, and you place a reference to it in `SupplyLocation`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your string is comma seperated, then do this,

```
String supply[] = (rs.getString("location_name")).split(",");

        for(int i=0; i<supply.length; i++) {
            Location.setLocation(supply);
            SupplyLocation.add(Location.toString());
        }
```